# Why does Terraform want to create the custom attribute again?

Tags: terraform, vmware, vsphere

I am try to use the Vsphere_custom_attribute resource. On the first run on an VSphere it runs fine but on the second run I get the error below.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this ? 
or did i just use it wrong ?

I use this Version of Terraform and Vsphere provider.

Terraform v0.12.12

- provider.template v2.1.2
- provider.vsphere v1.13.0

These are the code parts where i create the custom attributes and where i use it.

```
resource "vsphere_custom_attribute" "hostname" {
  name                = "hypervisor.hostname"
  managed_object_type = "VirtualMachine"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ...
  custom_attributes = "${map(vsphere_custom_attribute.hostname.id, "${var.vsphere_name}${var.vsphere_dom}" )}"
  ...
}
```

Error :

```
Error: could not create custom attribute: ServerFaultCode: The name 'hypervisor.hostname' already exists.

  on main.tf line 32, in resource "vsphere_custom_attribute" "hostname":
  32: resource "vsphere_custom_attribute" "hostname" {
```

terraform plan:

I do not understand why Terraform want to create it the custom attribute as it already exists.

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # vsphere_custom_attribute.hostname will be created
  + resource "vsphere_custom_attribute" "hostname" {
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + managed_object_type = "VirtualMachine"
      + name                = "hypervisor.hostname"
    }
```

Comment: Did anything happen to the state file between runs?

Comment: maybe, unmatch your resource of `aws` with resource of `terraform.tfstate`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're saying create the 'resource' instead of pulling the 'data' from vsphere. I had this confusion as well until understanding the 'vsphere_datastore' input required.

Try something like this (im using octopus deploy for variable replacement so ignore that im using invalid #{, should be ${ or just straight string for 0.12.x

```
...
data "vsphere_custom_attribute" "consul_backend_path" {
  name = "consul.backend.path"
}
...
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "windows_virtual_machine" {
...
custom_attributes = map(data.vsphere_custom_attribute.consul_backend_path.id, "custom_attribute_value")
...
}
```

Keep in mind, this requires the resource of the custom attribute to be in vcenter before this virtual_machine resource is created. Otherwise you will need to do a logic test to validate if the tag is required.